# Using simple linker script gives "relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S"

Tags: c, linker

I'm trying to compile this simple program with a custom linker script on an amd-64 linux machine

```
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    int* x = malloc(sizeof(int));
    while(1) {}
    return 0;
}
```

and

```
// script.ld 
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x100000000;
    .text : { *(.text) }
    .data : { *(.data) }
    .bss : { *(.bss) }
}
```

but if I do `gcc -T script.ld main.c -o main`, I get
a lot of errors like

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x12): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against symbol `__libc_csu_fini' defined in .text section in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a(elf-init.oS)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to link `main` at `0x100000000`, which is above 4GB boundary, but GCC (and your `libc`) are not set up for `-mcmodel=large`.

The default is `-mcmodel=medium`, which implies that the program is linked into the lower 2GBs of address space.

You would need to build both `main.c` *and* `crt1.o` with `-mcmodel=large` in order to link your executable at `0x100000000`.

Or just use `-fPIE` and `-pie` and your executable will load at arbitrary (but usually well above 4GB boundary) address.

Comment: If I use -fPIE -pie, am I sure that it will load after 4GB boundary?